# How can I go around an ambigous reference to overloaded definition error in Scala

Tags: scala, redis-streams

I am getting the error ambiguous reference to overloaded definition. My code looks like this

```
    override def process(record: Row) = {
    var asset = record.getString(0);
    var count = record.getLong(1);
    if(jedis == null){
        connect()
    }

    jedis.hset("click:"+asset, "asset", asset)
    jedis.hset("click:"+asset, "count", count.toString)
    jedis.expire("click:"+asset, 300)
}
```

and the error is from the line jedis.expire("click:"+asset, 300). anyone knows how I can go around this error

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `jedis` is from https://www.javadoc.io/doc/redis.clients/jedis/latest/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html

That class has four `expire` method overloads:

```java
long expire(byte[] key, long seconds)
long expire(byte[] key, long seconds, ExpiryOption expiryOption) 
long expire(java.lang.String key, long seconds)
long expire(java.lang.String key, long seconds, ExpiryOption expiryOption)
```

It looks like you're trying to pass a `String` and an `Int`; the closest method signature expects a `long` as the second argument, so try this:

```scala
jedis.expire("click:"+asset, 300L)
```

Note the `L` on the number literal tells the compiler you want a `Long` instead of an `Int`.